# reducing duplicated methods?

Tags: c++, oop, class, friend

So I'm working on a 2D space simulator and I have the resource manager '`calc`' that handles all calculations for everything. For example, from [`calc.hpp`](https://github.com/patrickpowns/corbit/blob/v2/include/corbit/calc.hpp):

```
var calc::eccentricity (object A, object B);
var calc::distance     (object A, object B);
var calc::orbitV       (object A, object B);
```

etc. However, the way I have my program structured is in my `calc` class I have

```
private:
object *ship    //the currently controlled ship
object *targ    //target
object *ref     //reference (from which speeds, position, etc. are calculated)
```

and to use the calculations given in the first example with these, I write three functions for each calculation function, like so:

```
var calc::ship_ecc      (object A){
    if(!ship)    //catches null pointers
        return NAN;
    return eccentricity(*ship, A);
}

var calc::ship_ref_ecc  (){
    if(!ref)    //catches null pointers
        return NAN;
    return ship_ecc(*ref);
}

var calc::ship_targ_ecc (){
    if(!targ)   //catches null pointers
        return NAN;
    return ship_ecc(*targ);
}
```

for `eccentricity`, and then the same for `distance` and `orbitV`. So I end up having four functions for every calculation. As you can see from [`calc.hpp`](https://github.com/patrickpowns/corbit/blob/v2/include/corbit/calc.hpp) this makes for plenty of duplicated code. And duplicated code is a Bad Thing.

### What my question is

Is there some way to call

```
calc.ship.targ.eccentricity();
calc.ship.ref.eccentricity(); //or variation thereof
```

or

```
calc.ship.targ(eccentricity);
calc.ship.ref(eccentricity);  //or variation thereof
```

instead of

```
calc.ship_targ_ecc();
calc.ship_ref_ecc();
```

? I'm wondering if you could do some fancy `operator()` overloading, or pass a function, or make a `friend` class in `calc`. Ideally I should only be able to access lines [`31 - 53`](https://github.com/patrickpowns/corbit/blob/v2/include/corbit/calc.hpp), which are all `public`.

Thanks!

EDIT: got an example for yall: https://ideone.com/jypJQS this is what it should output and how it is working now

Comment: From a design point of view maybe you want to encapsulate all calculation to an object.

Comment: I already have `calc` being my resource manager for calculations, if that's what you mean

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this changes too much your current code. But I think that the functions in calc should be members of object. So you could things like :

```
ship.eccentricity(target);
```

What confuses me (and what is probably the big problem here) is that you seem to define some hard relations in your calc object (the private members). What are those for ? From the code, I guess there is a calc object for every "ship". If yes, it would be an other reason to add the code to object instead of maintaining 1-1 relations between object and calc.

Comment: actually, in the [first version](https://github.com/patrickpowns/corbit/blob/master/classDeclarations.h) of this project I did that, but I didn't like how tightly it was coupled, so I incorporated that in my recent rewrite of this project, giving me [this much more minimal class declaration](https://github.com/patrickpowns/corbit/blob/v2/include/corbit/object.hpp).  Also, the way I have it set up is so that `calc` is a singleton, and `*ship` is just a pointer to any old object, not necessarily a ship.

Answer (score 1):

This might require a little bit of refactoring, but I think it's worth it. For a simple game, you can use OOP and Polymorphism to fix the issue.

First of all, create an `object` class.

```
 class Object {

 public:
    Object();
    ~Object();
 };
```

This object class would be a basis for all your objects in the game (ship, character, etc...).  You, then, would create a sub class for your `ship`.

```
 class Ship : public Object {


 };
```

This would allow an easy expansion to future objects that require the same principle.

In the object class, you would have some basic properties:

- physical (optional)
- dimensions
- speed (last calculated speed)
- controlled (bool - current controlling ship or not)

This would eliminate the need to have hard relationships with the `calc` and `ship` class.

Next, you would change your `calc` class to become general. You don't want to depend on a single ship object, this is cumbersome.

**Option 1**

You could create an instance of the `calc` class for each object. This `calc` instance would have access to the already available properties of the `object` and `ship` class.

**Option 2**

Create a general `calc` class that would require you to pass a reference to the ship/object instance. `calc->eccentricity(&ship, target);`

**Option 3**

Within a possible `manager` class, or a simple "global" variable. You could hold a reference to the currently controlled ship (if that's how your system works, I'm not sure). Or you could store the index of the ship and all instances are held inside a `vector<&Ship>`.

In a simplistic game, straight forward OOP will suffice, but if you want more decoupling, component based game design would be a better bet (in combination with OOP, of course).

Comment: Because I didn't make this at all clear in my OP, `calc` is a singleton, and I pass any old `object` to it. So effectively option 2 is what I have right now. However, see my answer, I'm changing this to a namespace. Also, I already have [`object`](https://github.com/patrickpowns/corbit/blob/v2/include/corbit/object.hpp) as a class. And I don't have variables like `controlled` in the object class, because I know something is controlled if it is pointed to by `calc.ship`. Not the best explaining in the OP.

Answer (score 0):

So I took this over to [/r/learnprogramming](http://www.reddit.com/r/learnprogramming/comments/15e1w8/c_are_these_member_class_function_passing/), and I got a good answer from zzyzzyxx (as always). His answer:

> What's wrong with simply having functions that take the required two or three parameters? They don't have to be in any special `calc` class. Maybe a `calc` namespace. I'm not sure it makes sense with the rest of your design, but what about making it a member function so that anything can calculate what it needs given a target and potentially a reference point if there's no sensible default?

So basically, don't worry about all this `calc.eccentricity(A, B)`, `calc.ship_ecc(A)`, `calc.ship_ref_ecc()` business, just say

```
calc.eccentricity(*calc.targ(), B)
```

Also, don't make `calc` a singleton, make it a namespace.
I'll go do that now.